# How can I parse a specific date string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

Let's say that I have date as a string, like: 02-12-2011

How can I parse it, and make it in format:

Friday, 02 December, 2011.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: a lots of duplicate questions are here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Check out [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog article on JavaScript date formatting](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) will help on the formatting part.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
var date = "02-12-2011".split('-');

var month = (date[0] * 1 ) - 1; // * 1 to convert to Number - 1 to subtract to 1 (months are from 0 - 11)
var day   = date[1];
var year  = data[2];

var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(month);
d.setDate(day);
d.setFullYear(year);

console.log(d.toDateString()); // will output Sat Feb 12 2011
```

You could also format the date differently by creating your own function that uses the getters `getMonth()`, `getDate()`, `getFullYear()`, `getDay()`.

If you'd like a lighter weight solution. Otherwise the link that @diEcho mentions looks good.

Also, the W3School references, while not the best for style, are pretty decent for a general 'get to the facts' reference about the various JavaScript Objects.

Here's a link to the Date object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: +1 for `month = ... -1`.  Stupid JavaScript Date object thinks months run from 0 to 11.  Not days, not years, just months.  I hate amateur-designed languages.